# Insert getValue in textbox + PhpRunner + Javascript OnLoad event

Tags: javascript, insert, textbox

I have a simple code on javascript onload event:

```
var ctrlCodigo_referencia = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'Codigo_referencia');
var ctrlNave = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'Nave');
```

And i have the follow :

```
    // Test

ctrlNave.on('change', function(e){
if (this.getValue()!== ''){
alert(this.getValue()); //show popup with the value selected in the combobox

//ctrlCodigo_referencia.getValue('this');
ctrlCodigo_referencia.getStringValue();
}}); //that is a want to insert in textbox ctrlCodigo_referencia
// Test
```

Comment: what is ctrlNave? Can you please share HTML and JS code with comments?

Comment: I use phprunner.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery is simple :

```
$("#ctrlNave").change(function(){
    if($(this).val()!=="")
        $("#ctrlCodeRef").text($(this).val());
});
```

If you are not importing jquery :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This code works if the names of the inputboxes are "id"s

Answer (score 0):

I find.

```
ctrlNave.on('change', function(e){
if (this.getValue()!== ''){
alert(this.getValue());
ctrlCodigo_referencia.setValue(this.getValue()) ;
```

Thanks all